# Twitter Bootstrap - borders

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I just started using Twitter Bootstrap, and I have a question about how to best add a border to a parent element?

for instance, if I have

```
 <div class="main-area span12">
    <div class="row">
       <div class="span9">
            //Maybe some description text
       </div>
       <div class="span3">
            //Maybe a button or something
       </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

If I apply a border like so:

```css
.main-area {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

The grid system will break and kick `span3` down to the next row because of the added width of the border......Is there a good way to be able to add things like borders or padding to the parent `<div>`s like this?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

If you look at Twitter's own [container-app.html](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/51e4e77034e14074cb442138e84b98efd288ccfd/examples/container-app.html) demo on GitHub, you'll get some ideas on using borders with their grid.

For example, here's the extracted part of the building blocks to their 940-pixel wide 16-column grid system:

```css
.row {
    zoom: 1;
    margin-left: -20px;
}

.row > [class*="span"] {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

.span4 {
    width: 220px;
}
```

To allow for borders on specific elements, they added embedded CSS to the page that reduces matching classes by enough amount to account for the border(s).

[image: Screenshot of Example Page]

For example, to allow for the left border on the sidebar, they added this CSS in the `<head>` after the the main `<link href="../bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">`.

```css
.content .span4 {
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 19px;
    border-left: 1px solid #eee;
}
```

You'll see they've reduced `padding-left` by `1px` to allow for the addition of the new left border. Since this rule appears later in the source order, it overrides any previous or external declarations.

I'd argue this isn't exactly the most robust *or* elegant approach, but it illustrates the most basic example.

Comment: What about using "margin: -1px;" for "border:1px ..."

Comment: pretty old solution. doesn't work well with current bootstrap version.

Answer (score 47):

Another solution I ran across tonight, which worked for my needs, was to add `box-sizing` attributes:

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

These attributes force the border to be part of the box model's width and height and correct the issue as well.

According to [caniuse.com » box-sizing](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css3-boxsizing), `box-sizing` is supported in IE8+.

If you're using LESS or Sass there is a Bootstrap mixin for this.

LESS:

```
.box-sizing(border-box);
```

Sass:

```
@include box-sizing(border-box);
```

Comment: If you're using Twitter Bootstrap with their LESS css implementation, there's actually a mix-in for that. `.box-sizing(border-box);`

Comment: The magnanimous El Goog says [version 8 and up](http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing) (91% supported).

Comment: Awesome solution.  Kudos for this

Comment: Could you please clarify: on which element should that style be applied? TA

Comment: The simplest answer is to put those attributes in their own CSS class, such as `border-boxed`. Then apply them to any .span element you would add a border to. For example, I could have a <div class="span12 bordered border-boxed">