# Bootstrap box-sizing with sass?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, less

After reading this post: [Using box-sizing : border-box with Twitter Bootstrap 2.x, can we do it easily without breaking everything?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15405837/using-box-sizing-border-box-with-twitter-bootstrap-can-we-do-it-easily-withou)

I've decided I want to try out box-sizing with a sass repo I've downloaded here:
https://github.com/thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass.

I've tried adding the following:

```
* {
-moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
box-sizing: border-box; 
 }
```

This works great, but it screws up my input forms height. Reading the above post comments on using box-sizing content on input forms. But obviously this is in less not sass:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
.box-sizing(border-box);
}

input {
.box-sizing(content-box);
}
```

Would anyone know how to get this working so my input forms are being squished?

Comment: border-box makes it so the padding doesn't change the size of the element, whats the issue, how about either a http://jsfiddle.net or 2 screenshots of before and after would be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use it within sass file also- try below code

```
*
  &:before, &:after     
     +box-sizing(border-box)


input
  +box-sizing(content-box)
```

Less code is now converted into a sass code. If Less code is working, then This sass code will definitely work for you

Comment: It was my fault I just added an extra { :)