# Layout issue, column drop to bottom

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Im quite new to twitter bootstrap, i try to do 2 column layout
Here is my code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span3 well">Content</div>
        <div class="span9 well">Content</div>
    </div>
<div>
```

Unfortunately the second column has been push to bottom of column 1

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uAs6k/301/)

Making the container of the column to `row-fluid` seems to fix the issue, but according to the bootstrap manual, u need a div container having the class `container-fluid`

I want to make fix layout, so i dont want to make container behave as fluid container.
Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using row, you will need to place the
wells inside the span3 and span9 divs.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span3">
            <div class="well">Content</div>
        </div>
        <div class="span9">
            <div class="well">Content</div>
        </div>
    </div>
<div>
```

As they are of a fixed width when used within a 
normal row, adding any padding or borders to the span divs will
cause them to wrap.

Alternatively you may wish to amend the bootstrap css itself, either by taking into account the borders and reducing the margin accordingly, or changing the box-sizing property, as per [Twitter Bootstrap - borders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793876/twitter-bootstrap-borders).  Bear in mind that box-sizing doesn't work with some browsers, e.g. IE7.

Answer (score 1):

In Twitter Bootstrap, `.well` class have padding, and that gives extra width to content of span classes.

Solution is:

```
.well {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;    
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/uAs6k/305/

Comment: i accept ngm answer cause it dosent depends on css3, btw i upvoted ur answer..thx again