# Best way to put a vertical line in the Twitter Bootstrap gutter

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<div class="row-fluid">

    <div class="span6"> Some content </div>

    <div class="span6"> Some content </div>

</div>
```

I want to put a vertical line down the middle of the gutter between these two columns.

The line is not the full length of the columns - so I can't just use a border.

I've tried changing my layout to span6, span1, span5 and using the span1 column for the line, but it messes up the space for my right content.

Any ideas ?

Comment: I think you should check this one [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793876/twitter-bootstrap-borders][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8793876/twitter-bootstrap-borders

Answer (score 1):

If you can go with the assumption that a modern browser (one that supports CSS 3) is being used, you can use the box-sizing property (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp) to override the default Bootstrap `.span6`.

You may also want to enclose this in a @media query to avoid strange left-side spacing when the browser is resized to a smaller width..

```
@media (min-width:979px) {
  .span6:not(:first-child) {
    border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
    padding-left: 10px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
}
```

<kbd>[**Bootply**](http://bootply.com/66990#)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answers. But the problem was not just a border. The vertical line has to be for only part of the length of the columns.

My solution was to use absolute positioning for the vertical line div & I had to give the span column a position:

```
<div class="row-fluid">

    <div class="span6"> Some content </div>

    <div class="span6" style="position:relative"> 
        <div class="thin_vertical_line" style="position:absolute;left:-15px;height:70%;top:0px;></div>
        Some content 
    </div>

</div>
```

The only remaining issue is that the -15px left assumes a gutter width (twitter bootstrap puts a left margin on the second span to get the gutter) of a certain dimension & with response twitter bootstrap this can change depending on screen resolution. -15px is safe but won't be quite centered on smaller devices.

Answer (score 0):

In Bootstrap 4.5.3 you could use this html code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
        <div class="col-md-3"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

With this CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 768px){
    .container .row .col-md-3:not(:first-child){
        border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    }
}
```