# How to add a vertical line in my web page Using Twitter Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I want to add vertical line in Web page my Code is

```
<div class ="container-fluid">
<div class="row-fluid">
<div class= "span2">
 #content
</div>
<div class= "span6">
#content
</div>
<div class= "span4">
#content 
</div>`
```

I want a vertical line after every span.

I have tried `<div class="verticalline">` but nothing happened.

Comment: .verticalline isn't a thing in bootstrap. Have you added any styles to that class? What does that class do?

Comment: no is there any class which help us to make a vertical line?

Comment: not that I know of, maybe try what this guy did: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17575193/best-way-to-put-a-vertical-line-in-the-twitter-bootstrap-gutter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There in nothing as vertical line.Instead of that you can you `class="well"` which is some what similar.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span3">
      <div class="well">
         #content       
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
      <div class="well">
       #content
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span3">
      <div class="well">
        #content    
       </div>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

I wish you try this and be helpfull.